# Print out an integer from an object using an accessor?

Tags: java

I've been trying to search for different way of retrieving a simple integer. Basically, what I want this program to do is just output the value of the variable "n".

```
public class Positive {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Positive2 result = new Positive2(5);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static class Positive2 {
        private int n;

        public Positive2(int n) {
            this.n = n;
        }

        public int get() {
            return n;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to use the accessormethod "get" in my solution. Do I have to override the toString method, and if so, how?

I tried adding a toString method like such:

```
    public String toString() {
        int str = n;
        return str;
    }
```

But I'm not sure if this is even necessary?

Comment: That toString method won't compile, but no, no need to override String

Comment: `System.out.println(result.get());`

Comment: you're not invoking the method, so you'll need to call it.

Comment: Or `public String toString() { return String.valueOf(n);}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this inside `Positive2` class

```
public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(get());
}
```

then

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {
    Positive2 result = new Positive2(5);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```